Birkhoff's theorem and Schwarzschild vacuum solution
Birkhoff's theorem states that any spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum field equations must be static and asymptotically flat, but the well-known Schwarzschild solution satisfies these conditions only for $r\ge r_{S}$.
What about the rest of spacetime?
The usual explanation, that behind the event horizon time and space exchange their role, leads to paradoxes. For example we cannot define that part of spacetime by the inequality $r<r_{s}$ because the $r$ means time and the $r_S$ means space, clearly two different things.
Even the term "behind the horizon" seems to be wrong. We should rather use the term "after the horizon has happened".
Another problem is the solution itself.  As a time-dependent vacuum metric, it should be derived from the non-static Einstein equations.
But, for me, the biggest contradiction in the story of an astronaut crossing the horizon, or better, to whom the horizon has happened is that he follows further his timelike geodesic although the time and space directions have exchanged their places. He is not moving in space, in respect to the event horizon, but in time.
Moreover, the plausibility of this picture is severely challenged by the fact that we are trying to describe the properties of vacuum spacetime in terms of the motion of matter there. What happens to the astronaut after a finite period of his proper time? My conclusion is that he remains spatially on the event horizon, which has expanded in area to accommodate his mass.
Which of these conclusions is incorrect?

Using the Schwarzschild coordinates at and inside the event horizon is not helpful. Use any of the coordinate systems that do not misbehave (Kruskal-Szekeres, Eddington, Gullstrand–Painlevé) and you avoid the problems.

Is it going to falsify some of my conclusions?

Your question seems a little unclear. For example you say he since then follows a space-like geodesic and no longer a time-like geodesic but the nature of a geodesic is coordinate independent. Since the geodesic is timelike in the astronaut's rest frame it is timelike, and timelike everywhere. Remember that coordinates are just labels we apply to points in spacetime and do not necessarily have the physical significance that we think they do in everyday life. The misbehaviour of the $r$ coordinate inside the horizon doesn't matter - it's just a coordinate.

Right you are. What I have tried to say was he is moving on geodesics but only in time and not in space.

@JohnRennie The Schwarzschild coordinates are perfectly valid inside the horizon. No coordinate system is valid at the horizon, because the coordinate transformation there is singular and thus mathematically meaningless. “Removing” the coordinate singularity (by an invalid singular transformation) is a widespread misconception, if not a deception.

@JanG You are correct on the horizon happening, something hardly anyone here understands. However, you really need to edit the question to fix references to geodesics, as everyone already has mentioned. For example: “After the event horizon has happened, there are no time-like circular geodesics in that part of spacetime.” - It should be “space-like”, not “time-like” here. And, as Yuktetez mentioned, this is incorrect. The angular coordinates $\phi$ and $\psi$ don’t change through (or after) the hirizon. (Cont.)

What we see as a 2-sphere in space (like a planet) actually is a 4D hypercylinder in spacetime. Its axis is timelike and is called the worldline. This cylinder is of the spherical type (as opposed to cubical) and is called a spherinder, because it is spherically symmetric (in space in this case). Inside the horizon the geometry is exactly the same, except the radius is timelike while the axis is spacelike, but the angular coordinates are the same and thus the cylinder is still spherically symmetric in space.

Does this answer your question? Does Birkhoff's theorem hold inside the event horizon?

@benrg It certainly helps, thank you. But I need to read and understand it before I can give you an answer.

@safesphere “After the event horizon has happened, there are no time-like circular geodesics in that part of spacetime.” I took it from equation (3). My result was that all circular geodesics there are space-like. I will check it again.

@JanG Well, circular timelike geodesics are time loops (closed timelike curves) that hypothetically exist only near the Kerr ringularity. In reality all circular geodesics are spacelike inside or outside the horizon. Their equation essentially is $dt=dr=0$ meaning constant $t$ and constant $r$ with only the angular coordinates varying. However the angular coordinates are the same inside and outside the horizon, so the circular geodesics don’t change their nature across the horizon. (Disclaimer: I am describing the hypothetical eternal Schwarzschild solution that does not exist in reality.)

@safesphere Is it possible that my space-like circular geodesic is time-like for you because its radius "inside" a black hole is actually time?

@safesphere For a circular geodesic in the Schwarzschild spacetime, the squared constants of motion are $k^{2}=\delta_{1} (1-r_{S}/r_{0})^{2}/(1-3/2 r_{S}/r_{0})$ and $l^2/c^{2} =\delta_{1} 1/2~r_{0}~r_{S}/(1-3/2 r_{S}/r_{0})$, see my equation (3). If the orbital radius $r_{0}$ is smaller than $3/2~r_{S}$ then to ensure that the $k^{2}$ and $l^{2}$ are real numbers the factor $\delta_{1}$ must be equal $-1$. Such geodesics are space-like.


JanG wrote: »Schwarzschild solution satisfies these conditions only for $r>r_S$«

That's not true, the Schwarzschild metric is spherically symmetric all the way down to the singularity. Even if you replace the singularity with a collapsing star, the inner shells don't feel the outer shells as long as everything is spherically symmetric.

JanG wrote: »he since then follows a space-like geodesic and no longer a time-like geodesic«

Also wrong, see MTW exercise 13.5:

You can't go from timelike to spacelike. You will never overtake a photon, not even behind the horizon. The general consensus is that if you cross the horizon you notice nothing special, so you neither become a photon at the horizon nor a tachyon behind it.

JanG wrote: »We should rather use the term "after the horizon has happened"«

You seem to confuse the horizon at $r=2$ with the singularity at $r=0$. The horizon doesn't happen to everyone who hasn't crossed it yet since you're still free to fly away if you haven't crossed it yet. If you decide to cross it you're not free to escape the singularity anymore, though.

While your answer is correct, you overlook the fact that the OP simply confused the geodesics terminology. He already admitted and explained it in a comment above and should really edit the question to correct it, but clearly there is no need to base your answer in his typo. Therefore the only tangible point in your answer is that the metric is spherically symmetric. While true, this does not answer the question and is really just a comment.

@safesphere - if his question is a typo he needs to fix it, otherwise i'm gonna assume he asked what he asked. if you have a better answer feel free to write it down, this is all i got for now.

Also, the OP is correct on the horizon “happening” to falling objects. You blame him for being confused while it is actually you who is being confused here.

Sure you are free to answer without trying to understand the question, but it doesn’t help anyone and doesn’t present you an a good light.

@safesphere - since you haven't written your own answer i'm gonna assume you don't have any, otherwise you wouldn't try to convince me in the comments but teach everybody in an answer, so i don't care about the light you try to shine on me.

It’s not my light. You are in a spotlight of the flaws in your answer :)

@safesphere - i don't care about that as well, if my answer is really incorrect someone else will write a better one, maybe i'll learn something of it then but as it stands right now there are no other answers, so we'll see about that.

@Yukterez"... since then follows a space-like geodesic and no longer a time-like geodesic." You are right, Rennie already pointed this out in his comment. I will change it.

@Yukterez"...all the way to the singularity." I am afraid I do not understand what you are saying. The way I associate the Euclidean distance and the "singularity" is not, as I understand it, a point of the spacetime manifold.

@JanG - If you fall from infinity so that your local velocity is simply the negative escape velocity v=-c√(rs/r) the spatial part of the metric becomes euclidean in your frame, see Gullstrand Painlevé coordinates where the local observers are such free fallers. In the classic Schwarzschild Droste coordinates the local observers are stationary, which in english means they'd have to be photons at the horizon or accelerated tachyons behind the horizon, that gives you weird sign flips which are unphysical. In the frame of any physical observer the metric is regular all the way down to the center

When you finally hit the center you do so with an infinite relative velocity though, which is kind of like zero velocity with a flipped space time axis, but until you hit the center everything is regular, just strong tidal forces and the fact you can't escape.

@Yukterez Just to my better understanding, the infinite speed relative to where? It cannot be the outer infinity, because the interior is detached from exterior spacetime.

@JanG - relative to the singularity at r=0, if you hit it you hit it with infinite relative velocity v=-c√(rs/0)=-∞, and also relative to the stars outside, from whom you're not detached inside since their light still reaches you inside, your light just doesn't reach them. On top of the gravitational blueshift you still have the kinematic redshift, which depends on your local velocity (if you cross the horizon with the negative escape velocity, i.e. free falling from rest at infinity, the net redshift from behind will be exactly F/f=1/2).
